# Android - Thread.sleep and Handler.postDelayed() freezes animated UI elements

Tags: java, android

In my activity, my app downloads a list of something from a website via an Http Connection. Before this list of things is displayed on the screen, I have a **Loading...** TextView with a little spinning ProgressBar to indicate that the data is currnetly being downloaded.

I noticed, that if I do any type of `Thread.sleep()` during the process of fetching the data from the web, it freezes the spinning `ProgressBar`.

Even if I put the method in it's own `Handler Runnable` so that it's on it's own thread, the animation freezing still occurs.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

A `Handler` is usually attached to the UI thread. Posting `Runnable`s to it doesn't change the fact that they will run on the UI thread.

Comment: Oh interesting... I must have misread that about Runnables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any application should do long running tasks on a seperate thread to the UI thread as any blocking calls will not allow the UI to update.

As the other poster said, using Runnables alone do not mean the code will be executed on a seperate thread. In this case the run() method will execute on whatever thread your Handler object was created on. Either subclass Thread or pass your runnabe to new thread object with [public Thread (Runnable runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Using [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) or [Threads](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) will help.

Also read [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) and [Multithreading For Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html). Following the above approaches will help you avoid ANRs

Answer (score 1):

The reason for such a behaviour is that:
When you do thread.sleep() inside a runnable, it is the UI thread which executes that runnable rather than the respective other thread which you created. Basically what happens is that when you post any runnable through the handler of the UI thread, UI thread will poll from its queue and execute the runnable; in this case the runnable will do sleep.

Hence no change in progress bar